# How can I get the email id list using Twitter Integration in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

**How can I get the Twitter email id list in the iPhone sdk?**

I'm **using MGTwitterEngine** and when I try the following method:

```
NSString *str2 = [_engine getUserInformationForEmail:@"yw8181@gmail.com"];

NSLog(@"User Email Id:--->%@",str2);;

so its return 0E156D0F-3E56-4935-9BE9-2A34786545ED so how can i display in tableView
```

I'm not getting email id list, please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Please format your question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you log it?

I'm guessing that it doesn't return an NSString, but another datatype like an NSArray?
Try this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [_engine getUserInformationForEmail:@"yw8181@gmail.com"];
for (NSString *item in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@",item);
}
```

Comment: its return 0E156D0F-3E56-4935-9BE9-2A34786545ED and i want to display in tableview so please help me

Comment: hello myarray returns 2B8EC544-AFE3-45B3-B348-CA2B54C3B39E so how can i display that data in tableview any idea?

Comment: I don't know what that code is - you'll have to look into the documentation for getUserInformationForEmail:

Comment: No its not working...My array returns 96856FCF-2D7D-41DF-A482-508A741E03FB.so how can i solve this issue...??????